# A mathematical explanation for why variance of bootstrap estimates decreases

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, data-science, sampling

I am trying to grok **bootstrapping** and **bagging (bootstrap aggregation)**, so I've been attempting to perform some experiments. I loaded in a [sample dataset from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/loveall/clicks-conversion-tracking) and attempted to use the bootstrapping method:

```
X = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
true_median = np.median(X["Impressions"])
B = 500
    errors = []
    variances = []
    for b in range(1, B):
        sample_medians = [np.median(X.sample(len(X), replace=True)["Impressions"]) for i in range(b)]
        error = np.mean(sample_medians) - true_median
        variances.append(np.std(sample_medians) ** 2)
        errors.append(error)
```

Then I visualized `errors` and `variances`:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('Number of Bootstrap Samples (B)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Bootstrap Estimate Error', color=color)
ax1.plot(errors, color=color, alpha=0.7)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('Bootstrap Estimate Variance', color=color)
ax2.plot(variances, color=color, alpha=0.7)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.title("Relationship Between Bootstrap Error, Variance \nand Number of Bootstrap Iterations")
plt.show()
```

This is the output of the plot:
[image]

You can see that both the error and the variance decrease as `B` increases. 
I'm trying to find some sort of mathematical justification - is there a way to derive or prove **why the variance of bootstrap estimates decreases when B increases?**

Comment: If anyone can tell me what exactly is "too broad" about this question, I'd be much obliged. So I can reformulate it in a more specific fashion. I'm essentially asking "why does the variance of bootstrap estimates decreases when B increases?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are seeing is Central-Limit Theorem in play. When the loop starts, the number of samples from the population with replacement is small and the mean of medians (you call this error) is not representative of reaching the true population median. As you generate more samples, the mean of medians converge to true median asymptotically. As the convergence happens towards true mean, the samples from this distribution are not far enough to generate a large variance and it also reaches convergence.

Did that clarify? If not please elaborate what you are expecting to see while plotting them and we can discuss about how to get there.

Comment: Thanks! This generally makes sense. I'm studying this in the context of the bias-variance tradeoff for models like Random Forest, which are supposed to take advantage of ensemble models (each individually with low bias because of overfitting) averaged together (to reduce variance). So if we keep increasing `B`, this means the variance of our model predictions would decrease as well?

Comment: The essence of random forest is to have biased trees voting for their individual choice. By looking at all the trees decision together, the bagging classifier decides final class of the sample. As the number of trees increases, the variance decreases and is one of the key strength of random forest. However, increasing trees beyond some threshold(depends on problem) hence the computational effort to collect and fit a model yields incrementally smaller benefits. The individual trees are highly biased (unlike you stated) since they are fitted based on only selected features (not selected samples)

Comment: Hmm. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285866/why-does-a-bagged-tree-random-forest-tree-have-higher-bias-than-a-single-decis : `If we consider a full grown decision tree (i.e. an unpruned decision tree) it has high variance and low bias. Bagging and Random Forests use these high variance models and aggregate them in order to reduce variance and thus enhance prediction accuracy.`. Isn't the whole point of the random forests to allow individual decision tree models to overfit (low bias high variance) on selected features, and then aggregate them together to reduce their variance?

Comment: Also https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/09/30-questions-test-tree-based-models/, question 27 - the correct answer is D, which includes `Each tree has a high variance with low bias`?

Comment: Thanks for bringing the references up. As you could see from the answers to the stackexchange question you posted. Due to the random selection of features and due to random selection of samples for each tree, the tree is biased. It is more biased than unpruned decision tree.[Here](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print12.pdf) you can find in page 619 about bias in random forest. Since we are diverging from the topic in question, If I had satisfactorily answered your question with my answer, please accept and open a new thread. Happy to continue. See you around.